# Rails 4 + datatables: Sort / search will not work

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, datatable

I am trying to get jQuery's datatable to work for my website but I cannot get it to function on Rails 4.  When I try to sort the columns I get ther error: `jquery.dataTables.self-770bf6f….js?body=1:2525 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'data' of null`

Here is what I have so far:

**products_controller.rb**

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /products
  # GET /products.json
  def index
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.json { render json: ProductsDatatable.new(view_context) }
        end
    end

  # GET /products/1
  # GET /products/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /products/new
  def new
    @product = Product.new
  end

  # GET /products/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /products
  # POST /products.json
  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /products/1
  # PATCH/PUT /products/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.update(product_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /products/1
  # DELETE /products/1.json
  def destroy
    @product.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to products_url, notice: 'Product was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_product
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:name, :category, :price)
    end
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<table id="products" data-source="<%= products_url(format: "json") %>">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**products.coffee**

```
jQuery ->
    $('#products').DataTable
    "Processing": true
    "serverSide": true
    "Ajax": $('#products').data('source')
```

**product_datatable.rb**

```
class ProductsDatatable
  delegate :params, :link_to, :number_to_currency, to: :@view

  def initialize(view)
    @view = view
  end

  def as_json(options = {})
    {
      sEcho: params[:sEcho].to_i,
      iTotalRecords: Product.count,
      iTotalDisplayRecords: products.total_entries,
      aaData: data
    }
  end

private

  def data
    products.map do |product|
      [
        product.name,
        product.category,
        product.price
      ]
    end
  end

  def products
    @products ||= fetch_products
  end

  def fetch_products
    products = Product.order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}")
    products = products.page(page).per_page(per_page)
    if params[:sSearch].present?
      products = products.where("name like :search or category like :search", search: "%#{params[:sSearch]}%")
    end
    products
  end

  def page
    params[:iDisplayStart].to_i/per_page + 1
  end

  def per_page
    params[:iDisplayLength].to_i > 0 ? params[:iDisplayLength].to_i : 10
  end

  def sort_column
#       columns = [Drug.name, Drug.category, Drug.price]
#       byebug
        columns = %w[name category price]
    columns[params[:iSortCol_0].to_i]
  end

  def sort_direction
    params[:sSortDir_0] == "desc" ? "desc" : "asc"
  end
end
```

Comment: checkout this link man http://www.nikolatodorovic.com/nikolas-blog/rails-4-datatables-110-ajax

Comment: I'm trying and still can't get it working.  Im also having a tough time reading their HTML

Comment: what problem are you facing man?

Comment: I just dont understand how to pass data via ajax when the column is clicked.  the data being passed in my ajax request only contains the values in the cells.  It contains nothing about the sorting

Comment: @uzaif, It actually seems like the ajax request has all the information.  But my view isnt changing when the sort direction is changed

Answer (score 1):

After struggling for quite some time I cam up with the following edits to RailsCasts #340.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).on("page:change", function() {
    $('#products').DataTable({
    "Processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
            url : $('#products').data('source'),
            type: "get"
        }
    });
});
```

and more importantly.. **product_datatable.rb**

```
def sort_column
    columns = %w[name category price]
#   columns[params[:iSortCol_0].to_i] <-- used in video
    columns[params[:order]["0"]["column"].to_i] #<-- works in Rails 4
end

def sort_direction
    params[:order]["0"]["dir"] #<-- works in Rails 4
#   params[:sSortDir_0] == "desc" ? "desc" : "asc" <-- used in video
end

def fetch_products
    products = Product.order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}")
    products = products.page(page).per_page(per_page)
    if params[:search]["value"] != "" #<-- new
      products = products.where("name like :search or category like :search", search: "%#{params[:search]["value"]}%") #<--- new
    end
    products
end
```

Comment: did you got the solution?